# How can I sort a file with a specific string as the sorting key in bash?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

So I have a **events.csv** file with:

- Date as the key and format : *DDMMYYHHMM*
- Name of the event
- Additional (optional info)

And I want to sort them according to current date.

[image: Cat the events]

The next step for me was:

```
cur_date=$(date +%d%m%y | sed s/0/\ /)
cat "events.csv" | sort -rk $cur_date
```

To get rid of the leading 0s.

The output is falsely sorted.
Should I sort first the year, then the month, then the day?

Any ideas?

Comment: Please don't post a link to a picture of your input, post the actual input instead. Also, the `-k` option expects a column number, I'm not sure what you're trying to do with the date string here.

Comment: That sed command has a syntax error, by the way, there have to be three slashes.

Comment: Had you needed a full sort you could handle the dates with `sort -k1.5,1.9n -k1.3,1.4n -k1n `, but by the time I figured out that wasn't what you were asking for [Lewis M](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10325512/lewis-m) had already answered it well. :) I'll leave this in the comments in case someone searching for something similar can use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you say sort by current date, I am assuming you mean you want to extract all entries for today and sort those into chronological order.  If that is true, the following should work for you

```
grep $(date +%d%m%Y) _file_ | sort
```

It will extract all entries from *file* that have today's date. Since all of these entries have the same date, the sort then will take care of sorting by the time portion automatically.

Hope this helps.